# sass colon vs ampersand colon

Tags: html, css, sass

I am using sass for stying elements and am having confusion with the `:` and `&:`, and when it would be appropriate to use them.

what are the differences? when should we use which one?

```
.root{

    :first-child{
        color: green;
    }
    
    &:first-child{
        color: green
    }
}
```

which one is appropriate to select the first child of the `root` container

Comment: FWIW, I think this question is a little different than the marked duplicate because it is also dealing with confusion regarding the :first-child pseudo-class.  In regards to "which one is appropriate to select the first child of the root container" the answer is _neither_-- the first will output invalid CSS and the second will get the first-child that _is_ `.root`.  What you want, in CSS, is `.root > *:first-child` -- you can achieve that in SCSS through nesting if so-desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there is no `:` vs `&:`

Rather, the valid one is `&:`

```
&:first-child{
    color: green
}
```

and one shown below, that has `:` without `&` is invalid

```
:first-child{
    color: green;
}

//this one is an invalid code and doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

The [ampersand `&` is the "parent selector" in Sass](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/parent-selector), and will append the rule that follows it to the containing parent scope.  However, neither of the rules you have will work.  The first...

```
.root{
    :first-child{
        color: green;
    }
}
```

...would render to the CSS...

```css
.root :first-child{
    color: green;
}
```

...which would be invalid CSS, as the [`:first-child` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) expects to be attached to an actual CSS selector.

The second...

```
.root{
    &:first-child{
        color: green
    }
}
```

...would render to CSS as...

```css
.root:first-child{
    color: green
}
```

...but that rule equates to "the first of any children with the class `.root` should have color green," which is not what you desire.

For what you want--"to select the first child of the root container", you would want this CSS:

```css
.root > *:first-child {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <p>some content</p>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>some</li>
      <li>other</li>
      <li>content</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

...which equates to "the first direct descendent of any type in a container with class of `.root`.  This could be rewritten in sass a few different ways; with full nesting you could write it as

```
.root {
    >* {
        &:first-child {
            color: green;
        }
    }
}
```

...but I would probably simplify it to...

```
.root {
    >*:first-child {
        color: green;
    }
}
```